# Running tests on folders within folders from package.json

Tags: unit-testing, npm, mocha.js, package.json

I have an app with the `test` command set as follows in `package.json`:

> "test": "mocha --require babel-core/register --watch-extensions js **/*.test.js",

Unfortunately my apps folder structure goes deeper than that command allows me to. It looks something like this:

```
app
└── someFolder
    └── subFolder
        └── subSubFolder
            └── fileNeedsToBeTest.js
            └── fileNeedsToBeTest.test.js
└── anotherFolder
    └── anotherFileNeedsToBeTest.js
    └── anotherFileNeedsToBeTest.test.js
```

The problem is as the `test` command stands I can only test what is in `anotherFolder` but I also need the files in `someFolder/subFolder/subSubFolder` to be tested. I didn't want to specify exact paths because I have multiple instances of this occurring across the app.

How could I fix my `test` command to be able to find `*.test.js` files no matter how deep they might be in the folders?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your glob pattern `**/*.test.js` should be wrapped in double quotes (`"..."`), however, because it's specified in JSON they'll need to be escaped with a backslash, i.e. `\"...\"`.

Your `test` command should be changed to the following:

```json
"test": "mocha --require babel-core/register --watch-extensions js \"**/*.test.js\"",
```

This will find all files ending with `.test.js` in the root of your project directory many levels deep.

**Tip:** I'm assuming that you're `app` folder exists in the root of your project, at the same level as your `package.json` and `node_modules` directory. If that's the scenario, then the glob pattern `**/*.test.js` will potentially find any files ending with `.test.js` from the `node_modules` directory - which will result in those test's being run too. To prevent that you can negate the `node_modules` directory in your glob pattern as shown in the following:

```json
"test": "mocha --require babel-core/register --watch-extensions js \"{,!(node_modules)/**/}*.test.js\""
```

---

**EDIT:**

In response to the following comment:

> ...where does `{,!(node_modules)/**/}*.test.js` part of the command come from? What syntax is that?

[Mocha](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha) utilizes [node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) as one of it's [dependencies](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/package.json#L466). The syntax for that part of the command is defined by node-glob (...which is analogous to the syntax Bash uses for globbing/pathname expansion).

A reference for this syntax can be found in [Glob Primer](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer) section of the node-glob documentation.

**Explanation of the specific pattern used for this scenario:**

Let's breakdown the pertinent parts of that pattern...

```
             (A) Braced section
              │
    ┌─────────┴──────────┐
    {,!(node_modules)/**/}*.test.js
     │└──────┬──────┘└─┬┘ │└───┬───┘
     │       │         │  │    │
     │       │         │  │   (F) filename extension
     │       │         │  │
     │       │         │ (E) Single Globstar
     │       │         │
     │       │        (D) Double Globstar
     │       │
     │      (C) Negation section
     │
    (B) Comma-delimited
```

- **(A) Braced section:** The docs describe it as:

  > Before parsing the path part patterns, braced sections are expanded into a set. Braced sections start with `{` and end with `}`, with any number of comma-delimited sections within. Braced sections may contain slash characters, so `a{/b/c,bcd}` would expand into `a/b/c` and `abcd`.
- **(B) Comma-delimited**

  The *braced section* begins with a comma-delimiter because the next *Negation section*, (the part beginning with `!`), must come after another pattern - it can't be at the beginning. Here the initial pattern before the comma-delimiter has not been provided; in this scenario it simply implies the project directory (or perhaps more specifically the same/current directory where `package.json` is stored). We could actually change the pattern to either of the following and we would get the same results.

  ```
  {/,!(node_modules)/**/}*.test.js
   ^

  {./,!(node_modules)/**/}*.test.js
   ^^
  ```

  Note, either `/` or `./` were added to the pattern respectively before the comma-delimiter. It's the same as how we *may* define paths to assets in html, javascript, etc.
- **(C) Negation section**

  The `!` means *"don't match this"* or *"ignore this"*. The docs describe it as:

  > `!(pattern|pattern|pattern)` Matches anything that does not match any of the patterns provided.

  In our scenario it's used to ignore the `node_modules` folder.
- **(D) Double globstar**

  The `/**/` part matches any number of characters including `/`. Perhaps more simply it means scan all files and sub-folders, however many levels deep.
- **(E) Single Globstar**

  Match all all characters of a filename if/when they end with the filename extension provided (F).
- **(F) filename extension**

  Match all files ending with the `.test.js` filename extension.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you!And just out of curiosity, where does `{,!(node_modules)/**/}*.test.js\` part of the command come from? What syntax is that?

Comment: **Updated answer** - added explanation of globbing pattern as per your request.